# Fastest method of splitting image into tiles

Tags: python, image-processing

I have an array of bytes which are the RGB values of an image. For example the first three bytes of the array will be the RGB value of the top left pixel. i.e. `a[0]` is R, `a[1]` is G and `a[2]` is B.

This image is actually a grid of images, typically arranged in 2x2 form. Here's an example.

[image: Example]

I'm currently using PIL to split the image into 4 sub-images. This is the code I'm currently using.

```
def split_image_to_tiles(im, grid_width, grid_height):
    #This treats the image `im` as a square grid of images.
    w, h = im.size

    w_step = w / grid_width
    h_step = h / grid_height

    tiles = []
    for y in xrange(0, grid_height):
        for x in xrange(0, grid_width):
            x1 = x * w_step
            y1 = y * h_step
            x2 = x1 + w_step
            y2 = y1 + h_step
            t = im.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2))
            tiles.append(t)

    return tiles
```

This works, but it isn't particularly fast. Is there a better or faster way?

Comment: Why do you want to split them? Treat the other images as padding.

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question since I'm using Numpy and OpenCV, but I just had a very similar problem, where I wanted to split a *grayscale* image into a 2D array of tiles/subimages. I ended up doing it with

```
height, width = image.shape
tiles = image.reshape((GRID_HEIGHT, height/GRID_HEIGHT,
                       GRID_WIDTH,  width/GRID_WIDTH)).swapaxes(1, 2)
```

For a color image with more than one channel:

```
height, width = image.shape[:2]
tiles = image.reshape((GRID_HEIGHT, height/GRID_HEIGHT,
                       GRID_WIDTH,  width/GRID_WIDTH, image.shape[2])).swapaxes(1, 2)
```

After that you could simply do `tiles[y, x]` to reference the tile at that index.

Especially compared to other image processing operations, this method is effectively instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

In fact in terms of Complexity you can do nothing, it will keep going as a O(N) complexity where N is the number of the Tiles that you wanna get from the Image.

Regarding this, you should run a profiler to realizer where the time is really spending. And as you can guess the `im.crop` is the method where the most of time the CPU is stuck.

This is a typical CPU bound problem, the only way to find out a better approximation without try to optimize the cropping by it self is use as many processes as many tiles you wanna get. Why processes ?

In that case where we don't have IO bound the GIL matters, and we want to make sure that each Python interpreter gets the CPU without problems.

Then, my recomendation is use the `multiprocessing` Python module.